Angular transpose grid data in html display
my angular version is 18 and i am trying to display and perform some operation on grid data. Creating grid data initially which would me modifying in later operation.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-2wuhqk?file=app%2Fapp.component.css
The grid data shows perfect in console.log but not displaying in right format in html.

which I want to display in transpose way but that should not disturb the console.log of console.log(JSON.stringify(this.board[0])); which I need in same format for further operation.

The result I see is the same as your picture. Show us a picture of the wrong result that you see.

@Kaperto the picture is shown the result which is wrong. I want the same result but in transpose way.

you can switch the tag content to {{mycol.col| json}}{{mycol.row| json}}.

you can make a | transpose pipe that would transpose the thing just for the view

@Kaperto, I tried {{mycol.col| json}}{{mycol.row| json}} , it works in html but console.log in onSquareClick  does not show right value.

We can create another array, which loads the array in reverse of rows and columns, this will be used to show the transposed data.
TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export interface Square {
  row: number;
  col: number;
  value: string;
  selected: boolean;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  boardSize: number = 3;
  board: Square[][] = [];
  boardTransposed: Square[][] = [];

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createBoard();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.board[1])); // this is right.
  }
  createBoard(): void {
    this.board = new Array(this.boardSize).fill(0).map(() => []);
    this.boardTransposed = new Array(this.boardSize).fill(0).map(() => []);
    for (let col = 0; col < this.boardSize; col++) {
      for (let row = 0; row < this.boardSize; row++) {
        this.board[col][row] = {
          row: row,
          col: col,
          value: '',
          selected: false,
        };
        this.boardTransposed[row][col] = {
          row: col,
          col: row,
          value: '',
          selected: false,
        };
      }
    }
  }
  onSquareClick(square: Square): void {
    square.selected = !square.selected;
    console.log('onSquareClick', square);
  }
}

HTML
<div class="grid-container">
  <div *ngFor="let myrow of boardTransposed" >
      <div *ngFor="let mycol of myrow" class="grid-item"
          (click)="onSquareClick(mycol)" 
          [ngClass]="{ 'selected': mycol.selected }" >{{mycol.row| json}}{{mycol.col| json}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo

creating another array is not the solution because in code we process the main array which will not reflect in html in straight. For better solution I could fill array like
CreateBoard(): void {
for (let row = 0; row < this.boardSize; row++) {
this.board[row] = [];
for (let col = 0; col < this.boardSize; col++) {
this.board[row][col] = {row: col, col: row, value : "" ,selected: false };
}
}
}
i have managed the things but considering row as column and vice versa.
